# Windows Forms Excel Addin VSTO scaling for different DPI

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, dpi, autoscalemode

I have a WinForms Excel addin and and it was developed on a Win10 computer with a 1080p monitor with 100% scaling (96 DPI). When I change the scaling to 150% (144DPI) the form controls look mangled.

I'd like to set the addin to not be dpiAware but as far as I know you can only do this on the host process (Excel) and not the addin itself.

To change how my forms are scaled I can edit excel.exe.manifest in the Program Files folder and change dpiAware to false. However this makes the entire Excel process not dpiAware whereas I'd simply like to have my forms shown using the OS bitmap scaling (which is done when an app is not dpiAware).

Is there a way to do this without changing dpiAware for the entire Excel process?